# How to display the time in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I create the time when a post is posted, for example, **a minute ago**, **yesterday**, **2 days ago**?
**For my current problem, the problem is it just showing "just now", it will not change although time is passing.**

---

### Post.Kt

```
class Post {
    private var postID : String = ""
    private var postPublisher : String = ""
    private var postImage : String = ""
    private var postDescription : String = ""
    var createdAt: Long = 0L

    constructor()

    constructor(postID: String, postPublisher: String, postImage: String, postDescription: String, createdAt: Long)
    {
        this.postID = postID
        this.postPublisher = postPublisher
        this.postImage = postImage
        this.postDescription = postDescription
        this.createdAt = createdAt
    }

    fun getPostID() : String
    {
        return postID
    }

    fun setPostID(postID : String)
    {
        this.postID = postID
    }

    fun getPostPublisher() : String
    {
        return postPublisher
    }

    fun setPostPublisher(postPublisher : String)
    {
        this.postPublisher = postPublisher
    }

    fun getPostImage() : String
    {
        return postImage
    }

    fun setPostImage(postImage : String)
    {
        this.postImage = postImage
    }

    fun getPostDescription() : String
    {
        return postDescription
    }

    fun setPostDescription(postDescription : String)
    {
        this.postDescription = postDescription
    }


    fun getTimeAgo() : Long
    {
        return createdAt
    }

    fun setTimeAgo (createdAt: Long)
    {
        this.createdAt = createdAt
    }
}
```

---

### PostConnector

```
 holder.createdAt.text = Utils.getTimeAgo(post.getTimeAgo())
```

---

### Utils.kt

```
class Utils {
    companion object {
        private const val SECOND_MILLIS = 1000
        private const val MINUTE_MILLIS = 60 * SECOND_MILLIS
        private const val HOUR_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS
        private const val DAY_MILLIS = 24 * HOUR_MILLIS

        fun getTimeAgo(time: Long): String? {
            //val now: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val now : Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val diff : Long = now - time
            return if (time > now || time <= 0) {
                "just now"
            }
            else if (diff < SECOND_MILLIS) {
                "a few second ago"
            } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
                "a minute ago"
            } else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
                (diff / MINUTE_MILLIS).toString() + " minutes ago"
            } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
                "an hour ago"
            } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
                (diff / HOUR_MILLIS).toString() + " hours ago"
            } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
                "yesterday"
            } else {
                (diff / DAY_MILLIS).toString() + " days ago"
            }
        }


    }
}
```

[image: Example of image]

Can someone help me? Please help me, if someone knows how to solve this kind of problem. Very appreciate it if someone can help me.

Comment: fun getTimeAgo(time: Long) i am not understanding which "time" you are referring to? Can you tell me so I can help you.

Comment: time when posting something

Comment: use 

Log.d("TAG", time.toString()) and check using logcat.

Comment: nothing changes when I implement Log. Is it any wrong with my code?

Comment: Log is not a piece of code that evaluates. It is used to check what value was assigned to a variable at the time, control of the code was at that position.

Comment: i have posted a answer try that, hope it helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230108/discussion-between-idevesh-and-smile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **createdAt** variable is returning 0 value so kindly change the data type of the **createdAt** to long by removing the **" "** double quotes from the database value and store the values as long not string.

Comment: when I try this one, it shows 18705 days ago although this post is just uploaded.

Comment: @Smile i have updated my answer. Use diff == 0 and try.

Comment: appears this problem -> Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Long' and 'Int'

Comment: @Smile i have updated the answer again try this using toLong() or L

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming

```
fun getTimeAgo() : Long
{
    return createdAt
}
```

will return created MILLIS.

In that case your first if the condition will be always true.

```
if (time > now || time <= 0)
```

Please check created at the time. Using Log. Before if statement. write:-

```
Log.e("TimeFromServer",time.toString())
```

Comment: Using Log? I am very sorry because I am a new beginner, can you explain more. Thank you.

Comment: replace return if (time > now || time <= 0) {
                "just now"
            }

with 

  return if (diff <= 0) {
                "just now"
            }

Comment: And the log is used to check data. You can check log in logcat or in the run.

Comment: when I replace it shows 18705 days ago although this post is just posted.

Comment: fun getTimeAgo() : Long
    {
        return createdAt
    }


is not giving you the right time. Please check your data.

Comment: postMap["postCreated"] = System.currentTimeMillis()
I store this in realtime database, is it this causing that problem?

Comment: Are you saving data in double or string?

Comment: i store in LONG

Comment: when you convert 18705 days ago in mills it converts to today. are you using correct timing? postMap["postCreated"] = System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: I am not sure. I will check it again.